# Error: Trying to get a property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web

Estou executando a seguinte iteração e obtendo o erro *Trying to get property of non-object*, sendo o código:

```
                    @if(isset($propostas))
                        @foreach($propostas as $p)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$p->proposta}}</td>
                                <td>{{$p->descricao}}</td>
                                <td>{{$p->valor}}</td>
                                <td>{{$p->data}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button style="border: 0px; background: transparent;" class="ver_proposta" value="{{$p->id}}">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="cbx_status" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="Analise" {{$p->status->situacao == "Analise" ? 'selected' : ''}}>Analise</option>
                                            <option value="Aprovado" {{$p->status->situacao == "Aprovado" ? 'selected' : ''}}>Aprovado</option>
                                            <option value="Atualizado" {{$p->status->situacao == "Atualizado" ? 'selected' : ''}}>Atualizado</option>
                                            <option value="Pausado" {{$p->status->situacao == "Pausado" ? 'selected' : ''}}>Pausado</option>
                                            <option value="Finalizado" {{$p->status->situacao == "Finalizado" ? 'selected' : ''}}>Finalizado</option>
                                        </select> 
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
```

Comment: Amigo, você precisa ser mais específico. Em qual linha dá este erro, de onde vem estas informações?

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="cbx_status" class="form-control" name="propostas">
        @foreach($propostas as $p)
          <option @if($p->status->situacao->id == $p->status->situacao->id) selected @endif value="{{$situacao->id}}">{{$situacao->nome}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
```

Tente algo como isso, eu tive esses problemas também.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o erro está dando no relacionamento

> $p->status

Checa se todos os relacionamentos de proposta com status estão todos preenchidos.
Isso normalmente acontece quando o relacionamento chamado está nulo então não existe situação para status null.

```
$p->status->situacao
```